# System fails to boot and restarts with a single beep sound.

Tags: boot, motherboard

I am using Intel desktop motherboard DH55TC and Intel processor 530 core i3. Earlier it used to boot up with two short length beep sounds, but now after first beep sound OS is not booting and it restarts. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Is an error message displayed, or does the screen remain black? Can you enter the bios ?

Comment: Your motherboard manual is at http://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/desktop/dh55tc/dh55tc_productguide01_english.pdf and boot error codes (beeps and power LED blink) explanations start at page 67.